# Where does load-scripts.php load jquery.js file from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, debugging, firebug

I try to debug a javascript function called from Generate Thumbnails plugin in Wordpress. The function uses jquery. So the actual call that I want to debug occurs in jquery.

The problem is that default jquery.js inside Wordpress is minimized and therefore obscure. I changed that file with the uncompressed version of jquery.js file in wp-includes\js\jquery.

But when I debug that function with Firebug's debugger, Firebug still shows me the old, minimized version of jquery:

[image]

I copied the location of the script file shown in Firebug and opened it in browser: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load=jquery,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget&ver=368b0ffbc13bc55b5ae45ad40a5368d9

This time, the true, uncompressed version of jquery.js was opened.

It seems like Firebug opens the old version of jquery. I restarted the Firefox but it wasn't resolved.

What might be the reason of this problem? Is this Firebug related or Wordpress related?

Comment: May be it's browser's cache problem, try it to open in a different browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd agree with the people who commented on your question - it seems like a browser cache problem.

If it's a test system, one thing I'd suggest is setting the `WP_DEBUG` constant to `true` in your `wp-config`.  That'll download the uncompressed versions of the javascript libraries.  That has two advantages:

1. You don't have to copy different javascript files around, and
2. The file names differ from the standard ones (they have `.dev` in them, from memory), so you shouldn't hit any caching issues.

I'm assuming there's an uncompressed version of jquery in WordPress.  Apologies if there isn't; I haven't checked.  But in general I'd recommend this approach.

See [Debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) in the codex for more information.